# Setting eth0 paramaters in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

My pc is connected to DSL modem using ethernet cable.  At present I change eth0 parameters like mtu, txqueuelen  using ifconfig at terminal on each boot. I would like to change some parameters of eth0 permanently.How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the NetworkManager for this? On the other hand, if you are comfortable with command lines you could use /etc/network/interfaces (just google for this).

Comment: In Network Manager where can we change txqueuelen ?

Answer (score 0):

Unwise `txqueuelen` mtu is changing by simple `mtu` statement. Looks like that the only one way to define `txqueuelen` through the `/etc/network/interfaces` file is providing `post-up` statement.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.255

    mtu 9000

    post-up ifconfig $IFACE txqueuelen 10000
    # or
    post-up ip link set $IFACE txqueuelen 10000
```